# Python Square Root for Class Instances

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am currently implementing a class that can handle numeric data associated with physical units.

I would like to implement a way of calculating the square root of an instance. Assume that you have an instance of a class that has attributes value and name:

```
from math import sqrt

class Foo:
   def __init__(self, value, name)
      self.value = value
      self.name = name

   def __sqrt__(self):
      return sqrt(self.value)
```

I would like to implement a function similar to the magic methods like **add**(self, other) that would calculate the squareroot when I call the math.sqrt() function:

```
A = Foo(4, "meter")
root = math.sqrt(A)
```

should return call the A.**sqrt**() function.

Comment: `math.sqrt` is just one of many other functions, Python can't have dunder method for all of them obviously

Comment: I suspect there must be _some_ way to get sqrt to accept custom class instances. Otherwise, how does `math.sqrt(numpy.array([4]))` work?

Comment: It works because `float(numpy.array([4]))` works. If you can use `__float__` to return a value, then math.sqrt will return the square root of that value.

Comment: @wowserx, so if you implement `Foo.__float__`, then `math.sqrt(Foo(4, "meter"))` can execute successfully? That might be worth putting in an answer :-)

Comment: @Kevin It doesnt **really** work. As wowserx explained, it will only work on arrays with a single elements (because they can be converted to `float`). Try it with larger arrays and you will get `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: @Kevin It is already in one of the answers

Comment: @DeepSpace That's fine, here, though, because the OP is (or appears to be) wrapping scalar values.

Comment: @DeepSpace, are you referring to John's answer? That only has half of it - it mentions defining `__float__`, but it then says you have to explicitly call float() yourself.

Comment: @Kevin You don't have to explicitly call `float`

Comment: So we agree that John's answer isn't as concise as it could possibly be :-) Perhaps we only disagree about whether that merits a new answer, or a small edit on the existing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't without reassigning `math.sqrt` to a custom function. If you want to allow `Foo` to be cast to `int` or `float` you can implement `__int__` and `__float__` and cast before calling `math.sqrt`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value, name)
        self.value = value
        self.name = name

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.value)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)

A = Foo(4, "meter")
root = math.sqrt(float(A))
```

EDIT: According to the comments below, it seems that you can invoke `math.sqrt(A)` directly if `Foo` implements `__float__` due to how the math module is implemented. I would still rather be explicit than implicit.

Comment: Nice idea. but you don't have to convert `A` to `float`. `sqrt` will do that for you

Comment: Note that `math.sqrt` is somewhat of a special case, though; since `math` wraps a C library, it has no choice but to convert *any* Python object it receives to a machine float that can be processed by the underlying C library. In general, a Python function will not try to cast an argument to some other type.

Comment: @DeepSpace Is this behavior generalizable? It might be the case with CPython's math module, but it may not necessarily be so with other Python toolchains or perhaps other math modules and libraries.

Comment: You *can* reassign math.sqrt (without damaging the math module) by the way: def sqrt(x): print("ha"); import math; math.sqrt=sqrt; math.sqrt(5) => "ha".  I would make sqrt(x) look for x.\_\_sqrt\_\_ and then implement \_\_sqrt\_\_ in my class, even though that means even more delay.

Comment: You can also override `__pow__():` and use pow(A, 1/2). In other words, use 1/2 to represent square root.

Answer (score 2):

There's no trivial/out-of-the-box way to wire `math.sqrt` to call `Foo.__sqrt__`.

Just implement `sqrt` in `Foo`:

```
class Foo:
     ...
     def sqrt(self):
          return sqrt(self.value)

A = Foo(4, "meter")
root = A.sqrt()
```

If for some reason you insist, it can be hacked, but I don't see any reason why you would want to do that:

```
from math import sqrt

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name

    def __sqrt__(self):
        return sqrt(self.value)

orig_sqrt = sqrt

def my_sqrt(value):
    if isinstance(value, Foo):
        return orig_sqrt(value.value)
        # or return value.__sqrt__()
    else:
        return orig_sqrt(value)

sqrt = my_sqrt

A = Foo(4, "meter")
print(sqrt(A))
# 2.0
print(sqrt(4))
# 2.0
```

Comment: Agreed. I highly suggest the naïve approach written in the first part of this answer.

Comment: One can at least rewire math.sqrt in the __main__ module as I describe in my comment on MEE's answer.  I even suspect that hack would make other modules see the substitute math.sqrt but I haven't tried it.  (This makes me a bit queasy about the security of Python.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic method for `sqrt` like there is for other numerical functions.

You could define a `sqrt` method in your class, as pointed out in another answer.

What you could also do is make your own `sqrt` function which calls `math.sqrt` on an attribute of your class if passed an instance of that class.

```
import math

def sqrt(x):
    if isinstance(x, Foo):
        return math.sqrt(x.value)
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

This is however, rather hacky and wouldn't recommend it unless you absolutely need to call `sqrt` indiscriminately on a container of mixed types for some reason.